# Saving entries in background cause crash and still blocking the UI

Tags: ios, magicalrecord, magicalrecord-2.1

I get a response from a remote API, parse it and assign in an array, then looping that array to save each element in the entity:

```
        for (id element in arrayProduct) {

            [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {

                Product *product = [Product MR_createInContext:localContext];

                ([element valueForKey:@"Category Id"] == [NSNull null])?(product.category_id = [NSNumber numberWithInt:-1]):(product.category_id = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[element valueForKey:@"Category Id"] intValue]]);

 }];

}
```

The for loop code is saving into coredata, but after a while, the app crashes and the rest of entries are interrupted and so they weren't saved.

Here is the log while the for loop is performing save:

```
2013-06-10 11:54:15:461 App[2718:2311] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:] [Line 42] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x1fd88c70) NO CHANGES IN ** BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) ** CONTEXT - NOT SAVING
2013-06-10 11:54:15:471 App[2718:2311] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:] [Line 42] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x1fd88c70) NO CHANGES IN ** BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) ** CONTEXT - NOT SAVING
2013-06-10 11:54:16:099 App[2718:135939] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:] [Line 54] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x20d96320) → Saving <NSManagedObjectContext (0x20d96320): *** UNNAMED ***> on *** BACKGROUND THREAD *
2013-06-10 11:54:16:101 App[2718:96515] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:] [Line 54] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x20d966e0) → Saving <NSManagedObjectContext (0x20d966e0): *** UNNAMED ***> on *** BACKGROUND THREAD *
```

I am using `saveWithBlock:` method because others method like `saveInBackgroundWithBlock:` are deprecated.

I have few questions:

-shall I proceed the for loop inside the block, or should the block be placed inside the for loop?
-What method should I use to ensure the app doesn't crash? is the method saving data in background ? because UI still blocked while saving.

Comment: Why not put the loop INSIDE the block...? Also, can you post the crash log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing it to this...

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
    for (id element in arrayProduct) {
        Product *product = [Product MR_createInContext:localContext];

        // ([element valueForKey:@"Category Id"] == [NSNull null]) ? (product.category_id = [NSNumber numberWithInt:-1]):(product.category_id = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[element valueForKey:@"Category Id"] intValue]]);

        // that line of code is really hard to read. Changed it to this...

        product.category_id = element[@"Category Id"] == [NSNull null] ? @-1 : element[@"Category Id"];
    }
}];
```

I imagine it's trying to create and save too many contexts which is possibly causing the crash?

Also, what's the crash you are getting?

Comment: Yes, As I mention in my question, I should tried to put the for loop inside the block before posting my question.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't see that sorry. You will also find (I've also had this) that the merge with the foreground context blocks the UI. With your current method you may have hundreds of merges but with this you will only have one.

Comment: BTW, should I `[localContext MR_save];` to validate save? because I saw that in some blogs.

Comment: No, the block will do all the saving for you. No need to explicitly call save.